# Why is the object's color not being loaded?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, save, load

I've managed to save a 3D object's position, rotation, scale, color, and shape. However, when I try to load the object, the color doesn't display; but everything else is working fine. I tried using "newObject.GetComponent().material.color = colorOfObject" via a peer's suggestion, but the compiler doesn't like the syntax. Am I on the right track?

Note: I just included my code for the cube option to provide a shorter block of code, but I do have other shape options that the user can choose.

```
        // Saving
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(700, 330, 50, 30), "Save"))
        {
            // Saving the object's color and resetting it to white
            Color colorOfObject = rend.material.GetColor("_Color");
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("rValue", colorOfObject.r);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("gValue", colorOfObject.g);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("bValue", colorOfObject.b);
            rend.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.white);
        }

        // Loading
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(770, 330, 50, 30), "Load"))
        {
            GameObject newObject;

            if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("Shape") == "cube")
        {
            newObject = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            newObject.AddComponent<cubeControls>();

            newObject.transform.position = new Vector3(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("xCoord"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("yCoord"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("zCoord"));
            newObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("xRot"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("yRot"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("zRot"));
            newObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("xScale"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("yScale"), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("zScale"));

            Color defaultColor = Color.white;
            Color colorOfObject = new Color(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("rValue", defaultColor.r), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("gValue", defaultColor.g), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("bValue", defaultColor.b));
            //rend.material.SetColor("_Color", colorOfObject);
            newObject.GetComponent().material.color = colorOfObject;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
```

Comment: Could you include the "rend" variable type? Also are you sure that is not null/undefined? Your code looks fine and as you say, should work as it is. My only recommendation is checking the Unity documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.GetColor.html As you see, you can access the color calling material.color (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-color.html).

Comment: Yes, I'll go ahead and edit the question.

Comment: There is no `GetComponent()` overload taking 0 parameters in the Unity API. Is this a method you implemented yourself? Otherwise you are missing to give it a component type you want to get like `GetComponent(typeof(Renderer))` or `GetComponent<Renderer>()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found some other examples and I realized that it should be:

```
newObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colorOfObject;
```

But thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: This is just a shorthand for what you were already doing (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-color.html), but I realize now that  you actually might have not properly fetched the Renderer, it should be something like .GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() . Also, since this is just a syntax sugar you'll still run into the unique instance problem (but maybe that's not an issue in your case)

Comment: you already had it correct including the `<Renderer>` but the html formatting of this page removed the "tags" ^^ I fixed it for you

Answer (score 0):

If the material of the object is using a shader who doesn't have the *"_Color"* property then it will be ignored. Some included shaders in Unity use *"_TintColor"*, other just don't support any coloring.

nb: your method is going to generate a new material instance, and thus a new drawcall for each object. Have a look at **[MaterialPropertyBlocks](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.SetColor.html)** and use a **[GPU instancing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html)** enabled shader/material setup.

Comment: I just tried a different approach (see the edit above) and I was wondering if you had any input on it? This was proposed as a solution by someone on the Unity help forum so I wanted to see if this fixed my issue, but sadly it didn't.